# SQL statement inside a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sql-like

What I want to do is have a SQL join inside a table.
Here is what it looks like:

#### pie table

```
Id       type message
1        2    'hello'
2        0    'bye'
3        2    'meh'
```

#### cake table

```
Id      data     pieId   
1       70       1@2
2       6        2
3       8        1@3@2
```

That is what the two tables look like, and what I want to do is be able to select the cake table where `data = 70` and have it return the row 1 of cake table, and return rows 1 and 2 of pie table.

I don't really care that it returns them as a separate table, row, join, or column.

What I really want is to be able to ask the database for `data = 8` and be able to return `1`, `2`,and `3` from pie table. I don't really care how it works if you have any suggestions

So I want to be able to query the cake and get a dynamic amount of pies. Even the table can change if you can think of some way of doing this.

Comment: What SQL have you tried and why were the results unsatisfactory for you? If you have not yet tried any SQL - why don't you try googling for joins and see what you can find - and then try it... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you need to update your database design

I would get rid of the pieId from cake table and create a relationship table. Lets call it CakePies with Id, PieId, CakeId. Just add the relationship to that table

The query would be

```
    Select * 
from Cake c
Inner join CakePies cp on c.Id = cp.CakeId
inner join Pies p on p.Id = cp.PieId
where Data = 70 -- or whatever filter you want
```

**Update**
Your CakePies  table should look like the following:

```
CakeID   PieId
1        1
1        2
2        2
3        1
3        2
3        3
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example for fnSplitString:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/

From there, try:

```
SELECT c.id, c.data, (SELECT message FROM pie WHERE pieid IN (SELECT * FROM fnSplitString(c.pieid, '@') ) AS 'message'
FROM cake c
WHERE c.data = 8
```

Which is a bit goofy - you're definitely better off having a relational structure for the pieid column: For example:

```
cake table
Id      data     pieId
1       70       1
1       70       2
...
```

Comment: i didnt understand what a relational table was until you posted this thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.data, p.Id, p.type, p.message
FROM cake c 
INNER JOIN pie p ON '@' + c.pieId + '@' LIKE '%@' + p.Id + '@%'
WHERE c.data = 70
```